# Is every element of a complex semisimple Lie algebra a commutator?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, reference-request, lie-algebras, semisimple-lie-algebras

Let $L$ be a (finite-dimensional) complex semisimple Lie algebra. Then we know that $L = [L,L]$. Is it true that every element of $L$ must be a commutator?

Since a complex semisimple Lie algebra is a direct sum of simple Lie algebras, this question reduces to the case where $L$ is simple.

For example, we know that every complex matrix with trace zero is a commutator, see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/95537/does-the-set-of-matrix-commutators-form-a-subspace). So this is true when $L = \mathfrak{sl}_n(\mathbb{C})$.

But what about other families of simple Lie algebras? Is this known for classical simple Lie algebras? What about the exceptional Lie algebras?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, this holds for all complex simple Lie algebras. A reference is Theorem $A$ in the article [On commutators in a simple Lie algebra](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1963-014-05/S0002-9939-1963-0153715-4/S0002-9939-1963-0153715-4.pdf). The result can be extended to simple Lie algebras over more general fields.

Comment: Thanks. So according to the paper, this holds over any infinite field.

Comment: You are welcome. Yes, it even holds over finite fields of cardinality big enough, see the details in the proof of theorem $A$.

Comment: Do I understand correctly though that it is always assumed in this paper that the Lie algebra is split? That's how I understand the first few lines of paragraph 2 in there. Also, otherwise this result would contradict statement 4) of the other answer, and make statement 2) redundant.

Answer (score 7):

1) In addition to Brown Theorem above, it is worth noting the following "1.5" generators of such Lie algebras.

Theorem:  Let L be a simple Lie algebra over an infinite field k of char 0 
(or char not 2,or 3). Then L=[L, a] +[L, b] for some a, b in L.
In particular, every element of L is a sum of at most 2 commutators.

Reference: G. Bergman, N. Nahlus, Homomorphisms of infinite direct product algebras especially Lie algebras, J. Algebra, 2011, pp. 67-104. (Thm. 26)

In fact, there are some explicit "1.5" generators over C (complex field) 
which can be found in some papers by Panyushev.

2) Back to "every element of L must be a single commutator",
It is indeed true in COMPACT real semisimple Lie algebras

References: 
1) For a proof using Kostant Convexity Theorem, see Appendix 3 in the book by Karl Hofmann & Sidney Morris, The Lie Theory of connected Pro-Lie groups, 2007. In fact, this proof was communicated to the authors by Karl-Hermann Neeb.

2) For another "implicit" proof, see Thm. 3.4 in "Some Questions about Semisimple Lie Groups Originating in Matrix Theory", Canad. J. Math. Vol. 46 (3), 2003, pp. 332-343 by Dragomir  Z. Dokovi´c and Tin-Yau Tam. Their proof uses Dynkin diagrams

3) Another reference is by D. Akhiezer, On the Commutator Map for Real Semisimple Lie Algebras, 2015, arXiv:1501.02934

4) The question whether "every element of L must be a single commutator for any Real semisimple Lie algebra L" is an open question.