# Lie algebra generator that does not appear on rhs of the algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras, mathematical-physics

> Is it possible that in a lie algebra one may have a generator that does not appear on any of the commutators?

If the above line is too physicisty for you, maybe I can try to translate to a more mathematicians question:

> A lie algebra is a vector space $\mathfrak{g}$ equipped with an commutator map from $\mathfrak{g}\times\mathfrak{g}\longrightarrow\mathfrak{g}$ that satisfies the Jacobi identity. Is it possible that the range of this map to be a proper subset of $\mathfrak{g}$?

I hope the last question conveys the same message. Any reference or link will be of help too.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, that happens quite often, an extreme case being that the Lie algebra is commutative, i.e. $[x,y]=0$ for all $x,y$.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg I was about to post that as an answer. Why don't you do that?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: I wanted to leave the possibility open that I misunderstood or the question was misphrased and something more profound was asked. But I've upgraded it to an answer now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It happens quite often that the image of

$$ [ \cdot, \cdot]: \mathfrak{g} \times \mathfrak{g} \rightarrow \mathfrak{g}$$

is a proper subset of $\mathfrak{g}$. An extreme case is given by *commutative* (also called *abelian*) Lie algebras, where the Lie bracket is constant $=0$, in other words the above image is just $\lbrace 0 \rbrace$ (but $\mathfrak{g}$ can be any vector space you like).

Other examples are all *nilpotent* and even all *solvable* Lie algebras.

It is worth noting that in general, the image of the Lie bracket is not even a vector subspace (scalar multiples are obviously fine, but the sum of commutators has no reason to be a commutator itself). The case that *the space generated by the image* (which by abuse of notation is usually denoted $[\mathfrak{g}, \mathfrak{g}]$, whereas formally it should be something like "$\langle[\mathfrak{g}, \mathfrak{g}]\rangle$") is all of $\mathfrak{g}$ has a special name: Such a Lie algebra is called *perfect*.

Now note that your condition is even more restrictive than being perfect! (For examples of perfect Lie algebras where not every element is a commutator, cf. YCor's answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2365525/96384.)

As Tobias Kildetoft points out in a comment, on the other hand, a big class of Lie algebras for which indeed each element is a commutator are *split semisimple* Lie algebras, at least if the cardinality of your ground field is big enough (certainly over all infinite fields, and since you say you're a physicist, I assume you are interested only in $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$ anyway). This is a non-trivial theorem. See the reference in Dietrich Burde's answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/771802/96384. For an elementary but by no means trivial proof just for the case of $\mathfrak{sl}_n(\Bbb R)$ and $\mathfrak{sl}_n(\Bbb C)$, see user1551's answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/252324/96384

Comment: Though it is worth noting that the condition does hold for semisimple Lie algebras (at least as far as I recall, and I don't recall why it holds).