# Lie bracket of ideals is ideal

Tags: lie-algebras

I am asked to prove that given two ideals $I,J\subset \mathfrak{g}$ in a Lie algebra, then the set
$$
[I,J]=\{[x,y]:x\in I,y\in J\}
$$
is another ideal of $\mathfrak{g}$. It is somewhat easy to see that due to the Jacobi identity, for any $a\in \mathfrak{a},x\in I,y\in J$:
$$
[a,[x,y]] = -[x,[y,a]]-[y,[a,x]],
$$
so now I have only to check that $[I,J]$ is closed under sums (since each term in RHS is in $[I,J]$). I searched for previous posts and I don't even think this is true (see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/11258/olivier-b%c3%a9gassat)): I think there's a typo in my book and that $[I,J]$ should be defined as the linear space spanned by all possible $[x,y]$ where $x\in I, y\in J$.

Can anyone either confirm that the definition is wrong or either give a proof that shows $
[x,y]+[a,b] \in \{[a',b']:a'\in I, b'\in J\}
$ for $x,a\in I, y,b\in J$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is correct that $I$,$J$ and $[I,J]$ are assumed to be subspaces of the vector space $\mathfrak{g}$. So the definition of $[I,J]$ is, it is the *subspace* generated by all brackets $[a,b]$ with $a\in I$ and $b\in J$.

There are counterexamples for your definition, e.g., for $I=J=\mathfrak{g}$, i.e., a Lie algebra where the commutator subalgebra $[\mathfrak{g},\mathfrak{g}]$ does not consist only of commutators $[a,b]$.

[When is the set of commutators of a Lie Algebra not equal to its derived Lie Algebra?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2363402/when-is-the-set-of-commutators-of-a-lie-algebra-not-equal-to-its-derived-lie-alg)