# Deduce that $\mathfrak{sl}(2) = [\mathfrak{sl}(2), \mathfrak{sl}(2)].$

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras

Assume that $k$ is a field of characteristic zero. Show that the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{sl}(2)$ has no ideals but $\{0\}$ and the algebra itself. Deduce that $\mathfrak{sl}(2) = [\mathfrak{sl}(2), \mathfrak{sl}(2)].$

For the first part, I know how to exactly do it still I do not know how to deduce the second part, could someone clarify this to me, please? will I expand the commutator? but then I will get zero not $\mathfrak{sl}(2),$ am I right? or there is something that I do not know?

Comment: Since $[\mathfrak{sl}(2),\mathfrak{sl}(2)]$ is a nonzero ideal, and $\mathfrak{sl}(2)$ is simple, we obtain equality. This is what the hint was suggesting to you. Note that for a Lie algebra $L$, the commutator subalgebra $]L,L]$ is an ideal by the Jacobi identity - see [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4107926/lie-bracket-of-ideals-is-ideal).

Comment: The main work is to show that $\mathfrak{sl}(2)$ is simple, i.e., has only two ideals.

Comment: @DietrichBurde, Emptymind: I think that in the special case $I=J=L$ which we have here, unlike in the generality of the duplicate, one does not even need the Jacobi identity to show that $[L, L]$ is an ideal in $L$. It's a one-line proof at most: The commutator of a general element and an element of the space in question is ... well, a commutator.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Yes, you are right. I wanted to give the more general link, because this is also very useful. For the commutator alone there is no link.

Answer (score 1):

To show the second part from the first, just note that $[\mathfrak{sl}_2, \mathfrak{sl}_2]$ is an ideal in $\mathfrak{sl}_2$. And that it is not $=\{0\}$.

Comment: how can I show the definition of an ideal on it?

Comment: You can show it like [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4107926/lie-bracket-of-ideals-is-ideal).

Comment: @Emptymind: For that, I suggest to empty your mind from anything about the special case $\mathfrak{sl}_2$ here, and convince yourself that for any Lie algebra $L$, the so-called derived subalgebra $[L, L]$, which by definition is the span of all commutators inside $L$, is always an ideal. That proof should not take more than one line.

Answer (score 0):

To show that $\mathfrak{sl}(2)=[\mathfrak{sl}(2),\mathfrak{sl}(2)]$, we need to prove two things:

1. $\mathfrak{sl}(2)\subseteq [\mathfrak{sl}(2),\mathfrak{sl}(2)]$: any element of $\mathfrak{sl}(2)$ can be written as a linear combination of the three matrices
   $$
   h=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix},
   \qquad
   e=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix},
   \qquad
   f=\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\1&0\end{pmatrix},
   $$
   which satisfy the relations
   $$
   [h,e]=2e,
   \qquad
   [h,f]=-2f,
   \qquad
   [e,f]=h.
   $$
   Since $[\mathfrak{sl}(2),\mathfrak{sl}(2)]$ is the linear span of commutators $[x,y]$ with $x,y\in\mathfrak{sl}(2)$, it suffices to show that $[h,e]$, $[h,f]$, and $[e,f]$ are in $[\mathfrak{sl}(2),\mathfrak{sl}(2)]$. This is easy to see, since
   \begin{align*}
   [h,e] &= 2e = [e,f]-h, \\
   [h,f] &= -2f = -(e,f)+h, \\
   [e,f] &= h = [h,e]+[h,f],
   \end{align*}
   and all of these commutators are linear combinations of commutators in $[\mathfrak{sl}(2),\mathfrak{sl}(2)]$.
2. $[\mathfrak{sl}(2),\mathfrak{sl}(2)]\subseteq \mathfrak{sl}(2)$: this follows from the fact that $[\mathfrak{sl}(2),\mathfrak{sl}(2)]$ is a Lie subalgebra of $\mathfrak{sl}(2)$ (i.e., it is closed under the Lie bracket operation), and $\mathfrak{sl}(2)$ is a simple Lie algebra, which means that it has no nontrivial proper Lie subalgebras.

Therefore, we conclude that $\mathfrak{sl}(2)=[\mathfrak{sl}(2),\mathfrak{sl}(2)]$.

Comment: I can not see in the first part why $[h,e] = [e,f] - h$ could you clarify this please?

Comment: Also in the second line you are using parantheses and not square brackets ..... is this really what you meant?

Comment: Also, in the third line $h \neq [h,e] + [h,f]$

Comment: the third one needs multiplication by half I think

Comment: The last three equations in part 1 are a) wrong and b) not needed. That some commutators are in $[\mathfrak{sl}_2, \mathfrak{sl}_2]$ is trivial, but also not needed for this direction. What one should actually show in part 1 is that $h, e$ and $f$ are in $[\mathfrak{sl}_2, \mathfrak{sl}_2]$, and *that* follows from the first couple of computations and the fact that $1/2$ is in the base field $k$.

Comment: Also, part 2 is trivial, as the left hand side is very obviously a subset of the right hand side. Nothing about simplicity or subalgebras is needed. Which is good, because the statement that "a simple Lie algebra has no nontrivial proper Lie subalgebras" is plain wrong. -1 for this answer.