# What's the image of the bracket [A,B]

Tags: matrices, linear-algebra

What's the image of the map:$$f:Mn(K)\times Mn(K)\rightarrow Mn(K) $$
where$$f(A,B)=[A,B]=AB-BA$$
Moreover,what's the image when the map was restricted to $GLn(K)\times GLn(K)$ and $SLn(K)\times SLn(K)$

I have known that every element in the image have a trace of 0 and can be linear extended to the set of all that kind of matrices; 
Howerver,the image may not be a linear space and I want to know $\textbf{specifically}$ about what the set is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The span of the image of $f$ is given by the commutator ideal of the Lie algebra of $n\times n$-matrices, which is the special linear Lie algebra $\mathfrak{sl}_n(K)$, consisting of all $n\times n$ matrices of trace zero; see here:

[Derived algebra of $\frak{gl}_{n}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2419105/derived-algebra-of-frakgl-n?noredirect=1&lq=1)

About describing the image itself, starting with elementary matrices $E_{ij}$ gives elements of the image, and for $\mathfrak{sl}(n,K)$ in fact every element is itself a commutator, and not just a linear combination of commutators:

[Is every element of a complex semisimple Lie algebra a commutator?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/769881/is-every-element-of-a-complex-semisimple-lie-algebra-a-commutator)

Comment: Derived subgroups are about "multiplicative" commutators defined as $[A,B]=AB(BA)^{-1}$. It's not immediately clear that they have something to do with "additive" commutators $[A,B]=AB-BA$.

Comment: I have edited the answer.