# Why can linear operators have $[A,B]=I$ in infinite dimensions when it is impossible in finite dimensions?

Tags: matrices, lie-algebras, trace, quantum-mechanics

For any $n\times n$ matrices $A,B$, we have $\text{Tr}(AB)=\text{Tr}(BA)$. This can be easily proved by algebraic summation. Thus $\text{Tr}([A,B])=\text{Tr}(AB-BA)=0$. Also, $\text{Tr}(kI)=kn$. Therefore $[A,B]=kI$ is impossible for all $A,B$.

But if we look at infinite dimensional Hilbert spaces (let's use $L^2(\mathbb R)$ in quantum mechanics as an example), we can actually have the conical commutation relation $[x,p]=i\hbar$ for the position operator and momentum operator $x,p$. That means the above conclusion about finite square matrix does not apply here anymore. I struggle to see why this is the case.

I try to rewrite the proof of the result about $n\times n$ for infinite dimensions. The problem is that I can no longer prove $\text{Tr}(AB)=\text{Tr}(BA)$.
$$
\text{Tr}(AB)=\sum_n \langle n|AB|n\rangle\\
\text{Tr}(BA)=\sum_n \langle n|BA|n\rangle
$$
I can no longer write out the entries of $A,B$ explicitly.

**So why $[A,B]=kI$ is impossible in finite dimensions but possible in infinite dimensions?** What *exactly* makes this difference?

EDIT: a comment below reminds me that the trace of an operator in infinite dimension can be undefined. This is a problem. But can anyone give more details about this?

Comment: Obligatory remark: it can happen that $[A,B]=I$ in a finite-dimensional vector space if the ground field is an appropriate one with a finite characteristic and the matrices have the right sizes.

Comment: The trace is no longer defined on all operators on an infinite-dimensional space. For example, let $V$ have infinite dimension and consider the identity operator $I: V \to V$. Then the trace should be $\dim(V)$, which is infinite.

Comment: You should change the title. You say "I struggle to see why this is the case" for the infinite-dimensional case, and not for the "finite matrix" case. There it is clear using the trace.

Comment: There is a section dedicated exactly to this in the book "Methods of modern mathematical physics" of Reed and Simon.

Comment: Precisely, it is Example 2 on pg. 274 on the first volume. [google books](https://books.google.es/books?id=bvuRuwuFBWwC&lpg=PP1&hl=es&pg=PA270#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Comment: An interesting example to play with might be $V = \operatorname{span}_{\mathbb{R}}\{1, x, x^2, \ldots\}$ the space of polynomials with real coefficients, and the operators $A: p(x) \mapsto xp(x)$ and $B: p(x) \mapsto p'(x)$ of multiplication by $x$ and differentiation. Then $[B, A]$ is the identity, and you can try writing out "matrices" for $A$ and $B$ to check what is going on, and why this cannot happen in finite dimensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $n\times n$ matrices over a field $K$ of characteristic zero, it is exactly because of the trace, that $[A,B]=I$ is impossible. Actually, *all* matrices in $M_n(K)$ of trace zero are commutators of the form $[A,B]$. This is usually proved with Lie algebra theory, because the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{sl}_n(K)$ of trace zero matrices with Lie bracket $[A,B]=AB-BA$ is simple and every element is a commutator - see this reference:

[Is every element of a complex semisimple Lie algebra a commutator?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/769881/is-every-element-of-a-complex-semisimple-lie-algebra-a-commutator)

The infinite-dimensional case usually is much more complicated and it is not surprising that many statements are no longer valid.